# How to get the file path before download is complete？

Tags: ios, download, nsurlsession

I use `URLSessionDownloadTask` to download file and it's delegate `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`only return the file location when download finished by 
`urlSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:)`.

How to get the file location before that?

I want to read data of the file while downloading. `URLSessionDataTask` can achieve this in some way, but it's not supported in background session.

Comment: Do you want to total filesize and progress?

Comment: Better than nothing, does it matter?

Comment: @a_tuo urlSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:) [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1409408-urlsession) Will help to get file size and download progress

Answer (score 0):

No, only data tasks (via [`urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1411528-urlsession) delegate method) provide the bytes as they come in. With download tasks, you can receive information about the progress, but not the contents.

Comment: But the data task is not supported in background

Comment: Yes, I know. I’m simply confirming your observation that, given that it only works with data tasks, you will therefore be unable to do that with background sessions.